# C# sort string of comma separated numbers

Tags: c#, sql-server

In C# what would you consider the fastest way to do this? The code will ultimately be part of a SQL Server CLR C# user defined function, but I don't think that is important for this question.

```
INPUT:  "1,3,2,5,4"
OUTPUT: "1,2,3,4,5"
```

The sorting has to be done by comparing the numbers as ints, not strings or chars.

I currently have the following but it is sorting based on strings, not ints. I could introduce a custom comparer but figure I would ask the question to see if others have any ideas before I do that.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString udfSortDimensionValueIDString(SqlString DimensionValueIDs)
{
    string[] values = ((string)DimensionValueIDs).Split(',');
    Array.Sort(values);
    return String.Join(",", values);
}
```

Using .NET 3.5 if that matters.

Comment: This will give you alphabetic sorting, right? so 1, 100 and 1000 would come before 2, right?

Comment: What about a `01` in your input? Should your output contain `01` as well, or will `1` do?

Comment: That's why he said he wants integer sorting, but implemented only string sorting so far... It helps to fully read the question.

Comment: Array.Sort(values , new AlphanumComparatorFast());

Comment: "The code will ultimately be part of a SQL Server CLR C# user defined function, but I don't think that is important for this question" - it may be - sorting will be potentially faster in SQL, so if this is used to develop an `IN` clause then parsing bay be unnecessary.

Comment: @knittl 01 can become 1. Given the backend database we will never get a 01 in the tables though.

Comment: @DStanley this will not be used for a IN clause. In initial testing (with the string sort instead of int sort) we are seeing a 95% improvement in time by using the CLR function over the TSQL equivalent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq; // no include required, just uses the namespace

  ...

  String Input = "1,3,2,5,4";

  String Output = String.Join(",", Input
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .OrderBy(x => x));
```

Comment: In my sample web application `Split` is accepting `char` not `string`. Is there anything that I need to know?

Comment: I think this will not be much faster than the original solution.  The only improvement is the sorting of numbers, while the bottleneck is the memory allocation of splitting the string.

Comment: @Bharadwaj: I'm sorry for typo: `Join` needs `String`, while `Split` wants for `Char`

Comment: So...dumb question. New to C# (do more with Ruby and Javascript)...how do I include the Linq DLLs? I added a reference to System.Data.Linq but getting "System.Array does not contain a definition for Select" error.

Comment: Ended up with the following. Thanks! The String.Join method didn't like that it was trying to join an int[] instead of a string[] so i just ordered by the int.Parse(x) instead of selecting that.  `return String.Join(",", ((string)DimensionValueIDs).Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray());`

Comment: For those interested in the performance gain, I tested this new CLR function against the TSQL equivalent (using a table function to split the string into rows, sort, then join back with for xml path). On 200K rows of unsorted CSV strings the CLR function processed in 4.174 seconds. The TSQL processed in 190.197 seconds which is a 97.8% reduction in time. (SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows 2008 Server VM with 8GB RAM).

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "1,3,2,5,4";
string ordered = String.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c)).OrderBy(i=>i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on the commas and convert each string to a number using the Convert library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx